# Syslog web interface recommendations?

Tags: syslog, logging

We've got a central log server (syslog-ng) and I'd like to provide a slick web interface for viewing the logs. Most of what I've seen are either horribly broken, outdated, or just fugly. I'm not very concerned about analysis, though it would be a bonus. Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you logging to mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splunk http://www.splunk.com/

Up to 500m data is free, any more requires a license key.  It will analyze many different kinds of log files, and has plugins for reading other kinds of log files outside of the standard (syslog and apache, and a few others I believe).  It has a very nice interface, and is very fast.

Comment: I agree with lsd, splunk is a quite nice log aggregator. Talking about commercial solutions you may throw an eye at logscape too (http://www.liquidlabs-cloud.com/products/logscape.html).